# representing a dynamic sized board of ints in mips

Tags: mips

I need to define some space to hold an array of integers that will represent a game board. This game board will be an nXn size, and n can be of 5-10 inclusive, depending on what the user specifies.

Is the best way to do this just create space for the maximum size it could be (10)?

```
            .data
            .align  2
game_board:
            .space 10 * 10
```

Comment: I suppose that depends what you want. Doesn't sound like a big deal to me, that's only 400 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sbrk` system call to dynamically allocate the needed amount of memory on the heap.
http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html